# Adaptive card for search UI using something like Type Sense

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot, adaptive-cards

Is there a way to create an adaptive card which provides a search UI - an instant search UI like TypeSense?

Our use case is as follows: we have a Teams bot that the users can use to do various things like approving invoices etc., but we also want to provide a way for users to search invoices. And for that we want to provide an input field where the user can type some stuff and as they are typing the instant search will provide results. We have the TypeSense server and the UI for that working in a web application. I am looking to see how I can provide it in Teams UI as a conversational way. I know I can embed it as a tab in Teams - but I am trying to see I can provide it in chat itself.

Regards
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **Typeahead search in Adaptive Cards** might help?

It provides a list of choices to enter text in the search field. You can incorporate typeahead search with Adaptive Cards to search and select data.

You can use typeahead search for the following searches:

- [Static search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/dynamic-search?tabs=desktop%2Ccsharp#static-typeahead-search)
- [Dynamic search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/dynamic-search?tabs=desktop%2Ccsharp#dynamic-typeahead-search)

Read more from Microsoft's official documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/dynamic-search?tabs=desktop%2Ccsharp